# Speed of copying data from PostgreSQL primary node to read-only nodes on DigitalOcean

Tags: postgresql, digital-ocean, database-replication

I have created a PostgreSQL database cluster, that consists of one primary+standby database and three read-only databases (each read-only database for a specific region).

During development I’ve faced with the next issue. When I write a row into database and then immediately (but after a promise is resolved of course) read the table, then I’ve got dataset without those new row (in most cases, but sometimes the dataset contains all expected rows).

But if I put some delay (600ms, for example), then the dataset contains contains all expected rows for all cases.

My question is: Does such behavior relate to some latency that is appeared because of copying data from primary node to all read-only nodes? If so, then how many time is needed for such copying? Or maybe, if the time is floating and depends on many factors, then how is it possible to measure this latency for my case?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: This is a [Tech Support](https://docs.digitalocean.com/support/) question for DigitalOcean.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver yes, it is. I've asked it on the DO community too ( https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/speed-of-copying-data-from-postgresql-primary-node-to-read-only-nodes-19bbd523-b4a7-427b-a116-77d7e77ebbca )

Answer (score 1):

You must be using streaming replication in the default "asynchronous" mode. That means that the commit of a transaction on the primary won't wait for the data to be replicated to the standby servers. So if you read from a standby immediately after you have written data to the primary, the data might not have been replayed on the standby servers yet.

There is also [synchronous streaming replication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/warm-standby.html#SYNCHRONOUS-REPLICATION): you would set `synchronous_standby_names = '*'` and `synchronous_commit = remote_apply` on the primary and reload. But if you don't want [replication conflicts](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/streaming-replication-conflicts-in-postgresql/) to let your transactions on the primary hang, you'd have to set `max_standby_streaming_delay = 0` on the standby servers. That can lead to queries on the standby being canceled, so you must be ready to repeat them.

Comment: Thanks @Laurenz ! Probably this solution is o.k., and I tried to do it but the Postgres hosted on DO infrastructure didn't allow me to make the changes. I applied another approach and set the primary node not only for writing but for reading too, and it works now.